# GridView is showing same column twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm truncating column `Description` text in GridView in this way:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="truncated" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" BackColor="White" 
                    BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="5" ForeColor="#000066" 
                    GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" 
                        HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
                    <Columns>
                      <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ControlStyle-ForeColor="Red" SelectText="Select" HeaderText="Select" />

                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderText="Description">

                      <ItemTemplate>
                      <div style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;width:100px">
                       <asp:Label ID="review" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' Tooltip='<%#Bind("Description")%>'></asp:Label>
                      </div>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>

 </asp:GridView>
```

Now the problem is that `Book` tabel have 10 columns, and if I select all columns from database like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Book", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

The column `Description` is shown twice in the GridView. First `Description` shows truncated text with the tooltip, and the second `Description` shows full text.

I know that I'm `Bind`-ing it in the GridView and selecting in the `SELECT` command in the code behind, but I need only the one with the tooltip in the GridView on browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add attribute to Gridview :

```
Autogeneratecolumns=false
```

This will solve your issue.

Following is the property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx

It will be as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="truncated" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" BackColor="White" 
                    BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="5" ForeColor="#000066" 
                    GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Comment: By using Autogeneratecolumns you would have to define every column (in a <Columns> section) you want displayed - which may be desirable, just saying.

Comment: Yes he will have to define every column he want to display in item template and rowdatabound

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that I was programmatically setting my columns in code so I was binding columns that were already set.  The solution was to check if the columns existed before setting them like this:

```
if (gvViewStudents.Columns.Count <= 0)
```

This solved my issue with the columns showing twice.